# WooCommerce: override product subtotal on the cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I override the product subtotal value, so it will be saved in session and passed the new value(s) also on the checkout page? Adjust product subtotal on the cart page or before calculate totals...

Looking for some hook, action, anything can be executed with best practice from the site's theme.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415783/change-cart-total-price-in-woocommerce) might help you