# Change Cart total price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am running into issues with the cart total **only displaying 0**

Essentially what I am trying to do is only accept a deposit total of a certain amount after all cart items have been added to the carts subtotal.

So for example if the customer adds $100 worth of items, they would only pay $10 initially or (10%) of the subtotal as the total value.

I took the code from here: [Change total and tax_total Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872057/change-total-and-tax-total-woocommerce) and customize it this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_total', 'calculate_totals', 10, 1);

function calculate_totals($wc_price){
$new_total = ($wc_price*0.10);

return wc_price($new_total);
}
```

**But the total amount shows 0.00** when that code is enabled. If removed the code, I get the standard total.

I also could not find on the woocommerce site where the full api is listed, only generic articles related to how to create a plugin.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be great.

Comment: You are facing issue of Data Type, $wc_price is string , not float, so your arithmetic operation is failing.

Comment: @Mohsin you were right, I thought woo-commerce would have returned the raw value of the subtotal to be manipulated, did not realize it would return a string.  The answer below helped as well as your comment to help me learn why I was not getting a float.  Thanks.

Comment: Great! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Since Woocommerce 3.2+ 
>   **it does not work anymore** with the new Class [`WC_Cart_Totals`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart_Totals.html) ...
>
> **New answer: [Change Cart total using Hooks in Woocommerce 3.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427950/change-cart-total-using-hooks-in-woocommerce-3-2/54428561#54428561)**

---

First **`woocommerce_cart_total`** hook is a **filter** hook, not an action hook. Also as **`wc_price`** argument in **`woocommerce_cart_total`** is the **formatted price**, you will not be able to increase it by 10%. That's why it returns zero.

> **Before Woocommerce v3.2** it works as some **[`WC_Cart` properties](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#$cart_contents_total) can be accessed directly**

You should better use a custom function hooked in  **`woocommerce_calculate_totals`** action hook 
this way:

```
// Tested and works for WooCommerce versions 2.6.x, 3.0.x and 3.1.x
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'action_cart_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
function action_cart_calculate_totals( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( !WC()->cart->is_empty() ):
        ## Displayed subtotal (+10%)
        // $cart_object->subtotal *= 1.1;

        ## Displayed TOTAL (+10%)
        // $cart_object->total *= 1.1;

        ## Displayed TOTAL CART CONTENT (+10%)
        $cart_object->cart_contents_total *= 1.1;

    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> Is also possible to use [**WC_cart** **`add_fee()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_add_fee) method in this hook, or use it separately like in **Cristina** answer.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec this worked perfectly. I appreciate it!

Comment: Yep. That it is accepted helps me find the solution to look at first. You do write the best answers.

Answer (score 21):

This does not answer this question. Loic's does. This is another way of doing it to show a line item of 10% off:

```
function prefix_add_discount_line( $cart ) {

  $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.1;

  $cart->add_fee( __( 'Down Payment', 'yourtext-domain' ) , -$discount );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line' );
```

[image]

Comment: gotcha, this is interesting Christina, as this will also help separate the difference between the actual total and the down payment they would need to pay today.  That is awesome!  thanks, I may incorporate this as well into the code for simplicity sake.  You rock

Comment: Cristina,  `global $woocommerce` with `$woocommerce->cart` is obsolete. You have to use directly the `$cart` argument object or `WC()->cart`.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected for the new stuff. Can't keep up. I find it a good moment when I get no errors with debug on ; -)

Comment: @Christina Hi when i added the code in function.php the entire section of cart got disappeared can u help me with that my woocommerce version is 2.6.14

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you since I can't duplicate the issue. Might want to check out the developer docs since they are for older versions. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/

Comment: @Christina Is there a way to add this before the coupon code is applied?

Comment: Many Payment Gateway doesn't support negative fees. So be careful, if you are using payment gateway.