# Additional fees based on product type in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

What I am trying to do is to add and display, to the checkout page, a new fee if the product type is an "auction". The problem I have with my code is that the new fee is displayed but not added to the total cost.

I've used this code 
[Change Cart total price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415783/change-cart-total-price-in-woocommerce)
and customized it with this function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'action_cart_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
function action_cart_calculate_totals( $cart_object ) {
    if ( (is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX')) || WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        if ( $values['data']->get_type() == 'auction' ) {           
            $buyerfee  = 0.10; // auction buyer fee
            $surcharge = $cart_object->cart_contents_total * $buyerfee;
            $cart_object->add_fee( 'Auction Fee (10%)', $surcharge, true, '' );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to use **`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`** action hook instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'action_cart_calculate_fees', 10, 1 );
function action_cart_calculate_fees( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return;

    $is_auction = false;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->is_type( 'auction' ) ) {
            $is_auction = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( $is_auction ){
        $percent  = 10; // auction buyer fee (in percetage)
        $fee = $cart_object->cart_contents_total * $percent / 100;
        $cart_object->add_fee( "Auction Fee ($percent%)", $fee, true );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works