# Change Cart total using Hooks in Woocommerce 3.2+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to add 300 to order total on woocommerce checkout page but woocommerce_calculate_totals hook doesn't do the job...

If I use var_dump($total), I see the correct result - int(number), but the total amount in order table is not changing.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'action_cart_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );

function action_cart_calculate_totals( $cart_object) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( !WC()->cart->is_empty() ):


        $total = $cart_object->cart_contents_total += 300;

        var_dump($total);

    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> Since Woocommerce 3.2, the hook `woocommerce_calculate_totals` doesn't work for that. 
>   See explanations on this thread: [Change Cart total price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415783/change-cart-total-price-in-woocommerce/43416407#43416407)

You will have to use one of the following ways using:

1) The filter hook `woocommerce_calculated_total` this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'change_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function change_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    return $total + 300;
}
```

2) The Fee API like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_fee', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_fee ( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $fee = 300;

    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Fee', 'woocommerce' ) , $fee, false );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or also in any plugin file.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine! One question: Why do you use the second argument $cart in your function 'change_calculated_total'.

Comment: still useful indeed @VitKashchuk

Comment: @LoicTheAztec How can I pass a parameter to this `change_calculated_total` . I want to pass user input value which is coming from cart page.