# Woocommerce: Change total price on Checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I changed the total price by using this WC()->cart->set_total(123456), but when i pay using a credit card, the amount paid is the normal amount, it should be 12345 but looks like WC()->cart->set_total(12345) only works to change the total price inside the shopping cart.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'mod_cart_total' );
function mod_cart_total() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
            return;

    WC()->cart->total = 12345;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly vague and not sure why you are trying to set the carts total vs an items total. But something like this I believe is what you are looking for.

[Change Cart total using Hooks in Woocommerce 3.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427950/change-cart-total-using-hooks-in-woocommerce-3-2/54428561#54428561)

Comment: Thank you Tim, but i would like to do it without hooks and i want to set the cart total