# fixed price for specific categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce, price

I would like to know some questions. We have a school where in a short time we will begin to enroll people online, especially with the Covid-19. We only charge 1 tuition even if the same student enrolls in several options. So I would like the final price to be the same regardless of the quantity of items. Well, I have found a code that solves me in part since the coupons do not work for me, discounts do not apply this for me, as a last option I could be worth it temporarily:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'change_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function change_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    return $total = 40;
}
```

So if there are 3/4 (maximum number of items admitted to the basket) they will only pay 40€
This code is from here: [Change Cart total using Hooks in Woocommerce 3.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427950/change-cart-total-using-hooks-in-woocommerce-3-2/)

This option is not the most correct, since it does not show a discount, it simply "tricks the system". But I would like this rule to affect the articles of a specific categories, only the enrollment, but the rest of the items in my store in other categories are charged at normal price. Could you please help me those 2 questions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to stackoverflow. I noticed you were missing a few tags. Please, review them and edit as appropriate. I'm not sure about [tag:hook-woocommerce] but I hope it is fitting.

Comment: hello @IsmaelMiguel I´m new here . Yes I forgot the most important lol. Thank you very very much!!

Comment: For clarity, some additional questions **1)** 
Isn't it strange to adjust the total price while the product price has not changed? for example you have product x in the shopping cart with a price of €5, product x has a quantity of 4, so the total price is €20 while there is then €40 displayed, 
isn't it a better option to change the product price based on certain conditions? (so that the total price changes automatically). **2)** 
you are talking about _"..maximum number of items allowed in the shopping cart_.." 
how is this limit applied?

Comment: Hello @7uc1f3r
In our case, these products in the store are not items themselves, reservations of a place to attend the next course at school. A fee to reserve a place for painting, yoga, music and math classes, for example. They all have the same price. But we charge € 40 if you reserve a place in a specialty or in 4. So I can't find the formula to make this condition. You could include these products in the same category: reservations, and if someone includes one or 4 the price is the same. Limit cart: woocommerce cart limit.

Comment: I have 2 ideas but I don't know how to do it: 1.Free products in this category and charge a fee if there is any product of these in the cart.
2. An automatic coupon that when 1 or more of these products are in the cart validates a final price of only € 40