# Change cart total for payment gateways In WooCommerce 2.6.x

Tags: woocommerce

I want to change the woocommerce cart total when user has bought certain amount of product items.I wrote my own code based on [Change Cart total price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415783/change-cart-total-price-in-woocommerce/43416407#43416407):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_total', 'six_boxsets');
function six_boxsets($wc_price){
//count how many items user has purchased and when it meets 6,change the total price to 999.
$itemcount = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
$product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( '40877' );
$in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
    if ($itemcount == '6' && !$in_cart) {
        echo "<span style='color:red;'>promotion-</span> ";
        $new_total = '999';
        return wc_price($new_total);
    }else{
        return $wc_price;
    }
}
```

It works fine on both cart page and checkout page.But after submit the checkout form and go to the payment gateway,it's still the old cart total not the one I tweaked.

In my payment gateway I used `$order->get_total();`to get the order price.

Really got lost ,can anyone shed some lights on this?

THX.

BTW,I'm still using woocommerce 2.6 version which works fine with me.

Comment: The hook that you are using is just used to display the formatted total on cart and checkout pages, but it doesn't change the real cart total. Instead for WooCommerce 2.6.x use `woocommerce_calculate_totals` hook like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415783/change-cart-total-price-in-woocommerce/43416407#43416407) using: `$cart_object->total = 999;`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec,It works now.But with this hook ,how can I add some extra texts before the price ,make the output like `promotion price-$999`.Thanks!